# provide time simulation in the stateflow chart

Tags: matlab, time, get, stateflow

I would like to get the simulation time when I simulate my stateflow program, and I do not know which command can give me the time at each step of runing.

Can you help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tic-toc`

```
tic
% doing something 
toc 
...
tic 
% doing something
toc
```

In general I would you `profile`

```
profile on
%Your code here
profile viewer
```

Output will show you how much time your code spends on every function call or on condition statements and etc. More info [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html)